# How do I add memoization to this problem?

Tags: python, project-euler

**Problem**
Starting in the top left corner of a 22 grid, there are 6 routes (without backtracking) to the bottom right corner.

[image]
How many routes are there through a 2020 grid?

**Solution**
Here is my solution

```
    def step(i,j):
    if(i==20 or j==20):
        return 1
    return step(i+1,j)+step(i,j+1)
print step(0,0)
```

But this takes too long to run, how can this be optimized?

Comment: How to add memoization? Write a decorator to store the results. This is a common homework problem so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @JeffMercado I tried doing that and it wasn't working, but it worked now :)

Comment: a google search returns http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally my memoization technique worked and the result appears in less than a sec

```
    cache = []
for i in range(20):
    cache.append([])
    for j in range(20):
        cache[i].append(0)

def step(i,j):
    if(i==2 or j==2):
        return 1
    if(cache[i][j]>0):
        return cache[i][j]
    cache[i][j] = step(i+1,j)+step(i,j+1)
    return cache[i][j]
print step(0,0)
```

Another optimization I have added (since step(i,j) is same as step(j,i))

```
    cache = []
for i in range(20):
    cache.append([])
    for j in range(20):
        cache[i].append(0)

def step(i,j):
    if(i==20 or j==20):
        return 1
    if(cache[i][j]>0):
        return cache[i][j]
    cache[i][j] = step(i+1,j)+step(i,j+1)
    cache[j][i] = cache[i][j]
    return cache[i][j]
print step(0,0)
```